# openquery issue in SQL Server

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, linked-server, openquery

I am using SQL Server 2008 (let us call this source database server in this question discussion), and in SSMS, I have created a linked server to another SQL Server 2008 database (let us call this destination database server in this question discussion).

When I issue statement -- select   *   from   [linked server name].[database name].[dbo].[table name], error will be returned,

```
Linked server "ZS" The OLE DB access interface "SQLNCLI10" returned "NON-CLUSTERED and NOT
INTEGRATED "Index" ix_foo_basic_info_nf ", which is incorrect bookmark ordinal 0.
```

When I issue statement -- select   *   from   openquery([linked server name],'select   *   from   [table name]'), there will be no errors, any ideas what is wrong?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the `Index As Access Path` option set for the Linked Server Provider? If so, try removing this and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: "Index As Access Path"? New to me. :-(

How to check and why it causes the issue I desribed but no issues for openquery?

Comment: From this link, I find what means Index As Access Path, but can not find how to turn it off.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188095.aspx

Comment: This option can be found in Server Objects>Linked Servers>Providers and right click>Properties.

It sets whether the the query will use the linked servers indexes to try and retrieve data. Not sure about openquery, but I'm guessing it never uses indexes.

Comment: You mean the first form of SQL uses index, and openquery not using index? But why using index will cause issues?

Comment: There are many providers listed under Providers, like ADsDSOObject, MSOLAP, SQLNCLI, SQLNCLI10, SQLOLEDB, which one should I remove Index As Access Path properties?

Comment: Which ever provider you used when setting up the Linked Server. I think in your case it should be SQLOLEDB.

Comment: From where you see SQLOLEDB? I saw SQLNCLI10. :-)

Comment: It depends which one you have set up. Maybe you should look to see what each one is, to find the one you have used.

Comment: Actually I do not setup any provider explicitly. I just write SQL. Any ideas how to find which provider I am using?

Comment: If you have a linked server, you are using one of the providers.

Comment: I mean how could I quickly find which one I am using? I think to set every provider to disable "Index As Access Path" seems stupid. :-)